# Quick and easy jQuery scroll question

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm developing a website that adds certain classes to body when the user reaches certain parts in the page, etc. As a result, I have to bind a function to the scroll event.

Is it better to cache the `scrollTop()` like this (short example, the actual function is longer):

```
scrollcheck: function() {

    var top = main.documentquery.scrollTop();

    if(top > 60) {stuff}
    if(top > 220) {more stuff}
```

Or just use `main.documentquery.scrollTop()` in all instances?

(`documentquery` is `$(document)`, I remember caching that being good, but I'm not sure about `scrollTop()`)

Comment: Try http://jsperf.com/ for benchmarking :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's better to cache it, but it's also better to throttle the calls to this function. That will probably make a bigger performance impact. In particular, I would use a timeout pattern along these lines:

```
(function() {
    var _timeout = null;
    function onScrollHandler() {
        if (_timeout) {
            clearTimeout(_timeout);
        }
        _timeout = setTimeout(function() {
            _timeout = null;
            realScrollcheck();
        }, 500);
    }
    $(window).scroll(onScrollHandler);
 })();
```

There'll be a half-second delay after the last scroll for your function (called `realScrollcheck` here) to run, but in 99% of cases that's acceptable. Adjust the timeout at your leisure. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I already do that for the heavy stuff, Im might try doing it with a 100ms timeout on the rest of the function, but since it involves making stuff become `fixed` it needs to be pixel-perfect

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is better to store the value instead of calling it each time.